# Implementing a complex custom function row by row using rolling and apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
my_dict = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'salary': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    'location_vector' : [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [4, 5, 4], [7, 5, 4]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

    id  salary  location_vector
0   1   100     [1, 2, 3]
1   2   200     [2, 3, 4]
2   3   300     [2, 3, 5]
3   4   400     [4, 5, 4]
4   5   500     [7, 5, 4]
```

What I would like to accomplish is to apply a complex custom function to the `location_vector` column row by row.

I thought I would use `pandas.rolling` along with `apply` to implement as below:

my custom function

```
def my_func(arr1, arr2):
    # do stuff
    ...
    return new array
```

I wanted to create a new column and place the results there.

```
df['result'] = df['location_vector'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x, y: my_func(x, y))
```

UPDATE:
Here is my wanted result:

```
       id  salary  location_vector result
0      1   100     [1, 2, 3]        NaN
1      2   200     [2, 3, 4]       [1, 2, 3]
2      3   300     [2, 3, 5]       [2, 2, 5]
3      4   400     [4, 5, 4]       [0, 2, 7]
4      5   500     [7, 5, 4]       [1, 2, 5]
```

Please note that `df['result']` is the returned array from the `my_func`. This could be any array. I've just put some arbitrary numbers there

I get DataError as below:

`DataError: No numeric types to aggregate.`

How do I implement a custom function to the column row by row? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind showing us you wanted result?Because technically you wouldnt want the rolling column\

Comment: Just updated the post by adding the desired result column

Comment: Yes that's true. Removed my comment. _**How do I implement a custom function to the column row by row?**_ then it's already going row by row, so it's not clear what you actually need.

Comment: The custom function could be anything but let's say I want to calculate the distances between two vectors. So I take df['location_vector'] row 0 and row 1 and compute. Then move to the row 1 and row 2 and compute and so on... Then put all the results to the result column. Hope this makes sense this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly. This can be done as follows: in the `list comprehension` (many times faster than the loop), at each iteration I pass the current index to the `my_func` function, where the returned result is the sum of the arrays at the past index and the current.

```
def my_func(i):
    if i > 0:
        return np.array(df.loc[i, 'location_vector']) + np.array(df.loc[i-1, 'location_vector'])


df['result'] = [my_func(i) for i in range(0, len(df))]
df.loc[0, 'result'] = np.nan

print(df)
```

Output

```
   id  salary location_vector       result
0   1     100       [1, 2, 3]          NaN
1   2     200       [2, 3, 4]    [3, 5, 7]
2   3     300       [2, 3, 5]    [4, 6, 9]
3   4     400       [4, 5, 4]    [6, 8, 9]
4   5     500       [7, 5, 4]  [11, 10, 8]
```

Variant with apply. `x.index[0]` is the retrieved value of the current index. `Grouping` goes by indexes, that is, iterations line by line, except for the first line: `df.index[1:]`.

```
def my_func(x):
    return np.array(df.loc[x.index[0], 'location_vector']) + np.array(df.loc[x.index[0] - 1, 'location_vector'])


df['result'] = df[1:].groupby(df.index[1:]).apply(my_func)

print(df)
```